# Does Jest have a last afterall callback?

Tags: jestjs

Does the testing framework Jest have an ultimate after all callback? A callback that is only called once after all the other test files pass or fail? Or is there a way to achieve this with afterall? I'd like to run a generic teardown that will teardown the environment that is used by all the test files (that is setup before any of the tests are run).

Comment: Something like [globalTeardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalteardown-string) ?

Comment: @Teneff Thank you! Post an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest supports [globalTeardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalteardown-string)

and you can use it in **CLI**

```
jest --globalTeardown="<rootDir>/src/jest/teardown.js"
```

or in **jest.config.json**

```json
  {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "globalSetup": "<rootDir>/src/jest/setup.js",
    "globalTeardown": "<rootDir>/src/jest/teardown.js"
  }
```

or in **package.json**

```json
{
  // .... rest of the package json
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "globalSetup": "<rootDir>/src/jest/setup.ts",
    "globalTeardown": "<rootDir>/src/jest/teardown.ts"
  }
}
```